# HTML Scraping By means of HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape html by means of HtmlAgilityPack but so many hits makes the server busy and client totally unresponsive, is there any way to get partial results from the server request? I  want to show some string of words on client when server is doing things... using MVC 4 by means of a controller.

Comment: You will need to explore your problem area little more. Also I suggest to make it more simplified. Current structure of your question will just fetch in negative ratings so restructure it as well.